# Is this the only and good way to sync data between 2 databases programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, windows-services, synchronization

I have 2 same databases.One in production and another in local.I'm trying to write c# windows service to sync data from time to time from production to local database.
Here is a code snippet from my data sync service

```
 private static bool StartDataSync(string tableName, string connectionStringLive, string connectionStringLocal,string databaseName)
    {
        bool status = false;

        DataSet dsResult = new DataSet();

        Int64 maxId = 0;
        MySqlConnection conLocal = new MySqlConnection(connectionStringLocal);
        MySqlCommand cmdLocal = new MySqlCommand("pr_GetMaxIdFromTable", conLocal);
        cmdLocal.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        MySqlParameter[] parameters = new MySqlParameter[4];
        parameters[0] = new MySqlParameter("vTableName", tableName);
        parameters[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameters[1] = new MySqlParameter("vMaxId", MySqlType.BigInt);
        parameters[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        parameters[2] = new MySqlParameter("vExist", "0");
        parameters[2].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
        parameters[3] = new MySqlParameter("vDatabaseName", databaseName);
        parameters[3].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        foreach (MySqlParameter param in parameters)
        {
            cmdLocal.Parameters.Add(param);
        }

        conLocal.Open();
        cmdLocal.ExecuteNonQuery();
        int ifExist = 0;
        ifExist = Convert.ToInt32(parameters[2].Value);
        if (ifExist == 1)
        {

            maxId = Convert.ToInt64(parameters[1].Value);

            MySqlConnection conLive = new MySqlConnection(connectionStringLive);
            MySqlCommand cmdLive = new MySqlCommand("Select * from " + tableName + " where Id>" + maxId, conLive);

            MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdLive);
            adp.Fill(dsResult);



            MySqlCommand cmdLocalInsert = null;
            string insertValues = string.Empty;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dsResult.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                insertValues = string.Empty;
                foreach (DataColumn dc in dsResult.Tables[0].Columns)
                {
                    insertValues = insertValues + Convert.ToString(dr[dc]) + ",";
                }
                insertValues = insertValues.Substring(0, insertValues.Length - 1);
                cmdLocalInsert = new MySqlCommand("Insert into " + tableName + " Values(" + insertValues + ")", conLocal);
                if (conLocal.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    conLocal.Open();
                }
                cmdLocalInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        return status;
    }
```

I dont know if this is the only way of doing this or if this may cause any other issues in future.If any one can suggest any other method of doing this, it will be most appreciated.

Comment: You could also create a script using mysqldump to dump the data from prod and restore it to your local copy. It will probably be faster and less prone to errors. And then you can schedule the script to run at any time interval you want.

Comment: i'm in windows not in linux.And even if i create a mysql dump each time i have to copy the entire database but dat is not really needed

Comment: well i'm taking the max id inserted in the local db each time and fetching data from production server which have id greater than that Max Id.Dat avoids replication

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you two use the **Microsoft Sync Framework**.
It is amazing and allow you two sync databases In one way or both.

We use it at job because once you have provisioned tables it works like
a charm. Fast and effective

you can check here for mor info:

[Microsoft Sync Framework Database Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887608)

[MIcrosoft Sync Framework Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753.aspx)